# Karate test summary report in xml

Tags: karate

I'm trying to generate the JUnit style test report in xml format, but I'm not getting a summary report in xml, instead I'm getting xml reports for each test case. Also I'm getting a summary report for all the test cases in html and json format.
I'm using JUnit5 and the following code in my Runner class:

```
@Test
void testParallel() {

    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:myProject/features").tags("regression").reportDir("classpath:target/xml")
            .outputJunitXml(true)
            .tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
}
```

}

Please correct me if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: you are not missing anything, such a report is not generated by karate. perhaps you can contribute code.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterThomas for confirming.

Comment: no problem. by the way you are the first person in 5 years to have asked for this

Comment: haha, I don't know, but I was trying to publish a Karate report in Azure pipeline, with the summary of all test cases. I thought a JUnit summary report would make things simpler.

Comment: @PeterThomas had similar case using picklesdoc -lr link-results, xunit xml would be far helpful, as the cucumberjson format was not working

Comment: @sujaisd anyone is welcome to contribute code, it is all open source